Kubuntu 23.10 freezes normal I/O operations on SSD
I have set up a dual boot system with Kubuntu 23.10 and Windows. Windows is installed on one SSD, while the other SSD is divided into two partitions - one NTFS shared between both operating systems, and the other exclusively for the Linux system. The problem I'm facing is that the system completely freezes when I access the shared disk and do some essential I/O operation on it (such as searching a file).
This problem happens only on Linux, while the partition is accessed without issues on Windows. I also tried to check for the presence of bad blocks or symptoms of failure of the disk, but I haven't found anything in this regard.
